# Reasoning behind $tJ$ model

Tags: condensed-matter, operators

It's know that the Hubbard model at large $U$ limit at half-filling can be mapped exactly (up to $O((t/U)^2)$) to the anti-ferromagnetic Heisenberg model. However, I'm confused about the reasoning behind such process. Indeed, in most references (e.g., Altland), the full Hubbard model is "rotated" by an ansatz operator $H' = e^{iO}He^{-iO}$ and then projected onto the singly-occupied subspace, i.e., $P_S H'P_S$ is related to the Heisenberg model. I understand that you can probably argue that we only care about the effective Hamiltonian acting on the singly-occupied space since we are at the large $U$ limit, but why would we rotate the Hamiltonian in the first place?

Moreover, in Kitaev's paper *Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond*, section 5.1, he **seems** to be applying a similar procedure when perturbing the gapped $A_z$ phase of the honeycomb lattice model, though I am not certain how he got the self-energy formula Eq. (36).